# Cosmos DB Left Join

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

All of the documentation for Cosmos DB and it looks like it only supports the `JOIN`keyword, which seems to be a sort of `INNER JOIN`.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(c.id),
        c.OtherCollection,
    FROM c
    JOIN s IN c.OtherCollection
)
AS c order by c.id
```

This works fine and returns the data of documents that have `OtherCollection` populated. But It obviously does not return any documents that do not have it populated.

The reason for the join is that sometimes I execute the following query (queries are built up from user input)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT(c.id),
        c.OtherCollection,
    FROM c
    JOIN s IN c.OtherCollection
    WHERE s.PropertyName = 'SomeValue'
)
AS c order by c.id
```

The question is how can I have a sort of `LEFT JOIN` operator in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, joins in CosmosDB  occur within a single item. Specifically, joins are scoped to that item and can't occur across multiple items and containers.

In some cases, the objects or children are null or do not exist, then You can emulate **LEFT JOIN** with the check functions (**EXISTS** or **IS_NULL**) AND **EXISTS** expression.

Even, is a better practice to use **EXISTS** expression that **JOIN**.

Eg:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.id),
    c.OtherCollection
FROM c
WHERE (--Like a Left Join
    NOT IS_DEFINED(s.OtherCollection) OR s.OtherCollection = null
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL FROM S IN OtherCollection 
        WHERE s.PropertyName = 'SomeValue'
    )
)
order by c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB **[`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-join)** operation is limited to the scope of a single document. What possible is you can join parent object with child objects under same document.

It is totally different from SQL Join query which supports across two/many tables.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, I am aware that it's totally different from a SQL join query, but how am I able to `join` on the collection but also include nulls

Comment: Well, that is the expected behavior, because for the join all conditions are met per parent + children[0] and parent + children[1].

Comment: if you want unique values use ARRAY_CONTAINS. i am not sure if i got your question in correct manner

Comment: Yeah I understand that is the expected behavior. I need to keep the join as I query properties in that collection, but I also want documents returned that have no items in the collection.